# Is it possible to redirect a method call to another instance of the same object at runtime?

Tags: java, methods, call, instance

*Situation:* I have multiple states of the same object represented by different instances (which are made using a deep-copy). Now I want to make sure that, no matter which of these grouped instances is accessed, all operations that perform modifications are redirected onto the youngest of these instances<sup>[1]</sup>.

*Example:*<sup>[2]</sup>

```
//Let's create an object
MyObject mObj = new MyObject(...);
//Let's create a list of past states
List<MyObject> pastStates = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

//doing some operations on mObj ....
mObj.modify(...);

//done modifying mObj, now let's save it's state and then create a copy to begin again
pastStates.add(mObj.copy());

//more of this...
mObj.modify(...);
pastStates.add(mObj.copy());

//let's compare some old states for whatever reason (e.g. part of an algorithm)
compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
    if(o1.getA() == o2.getA()) {
        o2.modify(...); //wait, we modified an old state...
    }
```

Now this is a rather obvious example and probably a classic case of *programmer's fault*. They modified something that is clearly advertised as being a past state whatsoever... But say we still want to be nice and try to help and thus **intercept the method call and perform it on the correct instance** namely the youngest/master instance.<sup>[3]</sup>

*Question:* **Is there a way to do this with standard java?**
*Bonus:* **Is there a way that doesn't have a horrible impact on performance?**

*Background:* I'm experimenting around with different ways to make a library/engine, I'm writing for fun, harder to misuse by the enduser. As I will need these states internally anyways (snapshots in time for certain background functionalities), I would like to make them available to the enduser as well so they can profit of my statekeeping, e.g. for use in analytical algorithms.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> There can be multiple groups of instances of an object that are not related to each other; relation will presumably be kept by a one way link to the youngest instance which simply won't ever change.</sup>

<sup><sup>[2]</sup> This code is meant as an example, it is clear that this mistake could be prevented by the enduser paying more attention when writing code.</sup>

<sup><sup>[3]</sup> Now an easy way to **prevent** modification is to wrap the object into an immutable version which throws exception when trying to modify it > but we do not write this object ourselves and don't want to force it upon the enduser to write two versions of their own object if we don't have to...</sup>

Comment: give us an example, it is not so clear what you need

Comment: @Valijon did my best to write some example - please notice that this is more a question about finding away to do a specific thing, rather a question about solving an issue by doing it differently :)

Comment: I would create inmutable object with `timestamp` field. If I need to modify, I create new copy with modified value + timestamp. So, when you compare, you will always take the last one.

Comment: @Valijon Timestamp is not a very good choice, as the timer's resolution is nowhere near high enough to guarantee that you won't have thousands of objects with the same timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create two classes: an "inner" one which is immutable and an "outer" one that maintains a list of inners. (Note: I don't mean inner classes in the JLS sense, just an object that is fully controlled by its wrapper.)

Something like this:

```
public final class Outer {
    private final List<Inner> history = new ArrayList<>(); //history is inverted for brevity, 0 is the latest one

    public Outer(int x) {
       this.history.add(new Inner(x));
    } 
    public void add(int x) {
      history.add( 0, new Inner(history.get(0).x+x);
    }

    public Inner current() {
       return history.get(0);
    }

    public static final class Inner {
       private final int x;

       private Inner(int x) {
          this.x = x;
       }

       public int getX() {
         return x;
       }
    }
}
```

With this setup clients can only instantiate `Outer`, can only mutate `Outer` but have access to a read-only copy of all the past states. There is no way to accidentally modify a past state. There is no need for separate grouping logic either because each instance of `Outer` naturally only records its own history.

Answer (score 1):

Method interception can be done with AOP by using an *around advice*. AspectJ is a good tool for solving such problems. The impact on performance should also be no problem.

In an *around advice* in most cases you call *proceed* to execute the target method on the target object, but you can also prevent the method execution and instead do a method call on another object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using bytecode modification.

Actually, if it was done by AspectJ or other library, it would be implemented using proxies or byte code modification. But I'm not sure that this specific task is possible with Aspect programming libraries API.

You can find working example for your task in [this repo](https://github.com/Spikhalskiy/stackoverflow/tree/master/33842614).

This test from repository works fine:

```
    //Let's create an object
    MyObject mObj = new MyObject();
    MyObjectActiveRepository.INSTANCE.putToGroup(mObj, "group1");
    MyObjectActiveRepository.INSTANCE.registerActiveForItsGroup(mObj);
    //Let's create a list of past states
    List<MyObject> pastStates = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    //doing some operations on mObj ....
    mObj.modify("state1");

    //done modifying mObj, now let's save it's state and then create a copy to begin again
    pastStates.add(mObj.copy());

    //more of this...
    mObj.modify("state2");
    pastStates.add(mObj.copy());

    mObj.modify("state3");

    assertEquals("state1", pastStates.get(0).getState());
    assertEquals("state2", pastStates.get(1).getState());
    assertEquals("state3", mObj.getState());

    pastStates.get(0).modify("stateNew");
    assertEquals("state1", pastStates.get(0).getState());
    assertEquals("state2", pastStates.get(1).getState());
    assertEquals("stateNew", mObj.getState());
```

Shortly -

1. I use [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/) (Bytecode generation and modification tool) to redefine class bytecode before it has been load to:

   - remove final from class (if we have)
   - add field to save MyObject's "group" to address your (1) note
   - intercept call to `copy`(we need to copy "group" field additionally) and `modify` (to retarget call)
   - replace class code in classloader

```
TypePool typePool = TypePool.Default.ofClassPath();
new ByteBuddy()
    .rebase(typePool.describe("MyObject").resolve(), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath())
    .modifiers(TypeManifestation.PLAIN) //our class can be final and we have no access to it - so remove final
    .defineField("group", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .method(named("modify")).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(typePool.describe("Interceptors").resolve()))
    .method(named("copy")).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(typePool.describe("Interceptors").resolve()))
    .make()
    .load(InterceptorsInitializer.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION);
```

2. Implemented `MyObjectActiveRepository` which contains information about active object for group and "group" field related functionality.`Interceptors` with simple `copy` redefinition which add "group" setting and `modify`, which makes our retargeting.

I think it should be lite code, the most expensive part is reflection call to setter on group-to-object assignment after object creation (this part can be improved; if we use ByteBuddy - we can replace reflection with implementing new interface with `getGroup()` and `setGroup(String)` methods during byte code generation with delegating them to FieldAccessor.ofField("group"), so we will have fine effective invokevirtual thru interface). `modify()` should have near the same performance, because it doesn't use reflection, only fully generated bytecode. I didn't make any benchmarking.